# RegEx with pattern and matcher in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have a text/html file i need some information from it. Therefor i use RegEx like in the code below.

My Problem is, that I want the results of pattern p and pattern l in the same matcher because the order of the results is very important.
In my code the System.output has a wrong order because he prints the results of pattern p and then the results of pattern l.

How to solve that Problem?

```
        String pattern1 = "<img class=\"galleryElement shown\" data-src=\"";
        String pattern2 = "\" src=\"\" />";
        String pattern3 = "<img class=\"galleryElement shown\" src=\"";
        String pattern4 = "\" />";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern1) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern2));
        Pattern l = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pattern3) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(pattern4));
        Matcher m = p.matcher(res.toString());
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }

        Matcher n = l.matcher(res.toString());
        while (n.find()) {
            System.out.println(n.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: How to solve that problem? Use a parser..

Comment: Working with regex on html is a pain. If it's not problem to add a library to your project, then take a look a jsoup.org.

Comment: what do you mean? i cant just mix them because i have no order indicator

Comment: what you want to achieve using multiple regex pattern.

Comment: ? im using multiple pattern but i need to unit them in the correct order

Comment: I tryed jsoup but i have no clue how to extract the data i need like u see in the code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not defined the rules hence it's just a try. Let me know if you need some any modification in the pattern:

```
<img class="galleryElement shown" (data-)?src="([^"]*?)"
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/gH9wY6/2)

Pattern explanation: `(data-)?src="([^"]*?)"`

```
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional):
    data-                    'data-'
  )?                       end of \1
  src="                    'src="'
  (                        group and capture to \2:
    [^"]*?                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times (least))
  )                        end of \2
  "                        '"'
```

Sample code:

```
String pattern = "<img class=\"galleryElement shown\" (data-)?src=\"([^\"]*?)\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("<img class=\"galleryElement shown\" data-src=\"abc\" />");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: thx a lot, thats a very good solution!!
But why has match1 2 results? only abc should be the result of match1 in the online demo

Comment: because I have used two parenthesis `(..)` that is used for capturing groups. I used it to make `(data-)` as optional. No worries you always get it from index 2.

Comment: it works perfect, thank you very much! especially for the explanation, im starting to understand

Comment: if u have time: how about this patterns: (its the same like before just with this diffeent patterns)
String pattern15 = "<span class=\"flag update\">!</span>        <a href=\"/expose/";
   String pattern16 = "\" title=\"";
   String pattern17 = "<span class=\"flag\">NEU</span>                <a href=\"/expose/";
   String pattern18 = "\" title=\"";
my try doenst work well...

Comment: group all in single pattern. Make them optional `<span class=\"flag( update)?\">(!|NEU)</span> <a href=\"/expose/` using `?` and use `(...|...)` to make a OR choice.

Comment: how to group in just 1 group? regex101 says there are always 2 groups.
I didnt get it for this String(part) http://regex101.com/r/gH9wY6/3

Comment: sry i have another question:
How to make a capturing group optional, that means, wheni have 3 capturing groups I want re result 1. a-b-c 2. a-b-c 3. a-b-null 4. a-b-c. I dont want, that result 3 disappears because the 3rd capturing group doesnt match.

Comment: I suggest you to spend some time on regex pattern. writer some sample program then if you have any specific question then post it as separate post because It's not clear to me what are you asking and in which context? A complete post is needed to answer your query in correct way.

Comment: +1 for working answer **and** even understanding the question! (I had trouble with this one.) :)

Comment: ok thanks, i made a new post for tthe question, hope it is clear now:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066097/regex-with-two-captering-groups