# REGEX with two capturing groups

Tags: java, regex

I need some help for a regular expression:

I have this example code in regex101:

http://regex101.com/r/iW8hP4/4

```
dsgssgdfgdsfg <result1>A1<result1>
anythingiwith<>and"234and
newlinesandsoon
<result>B1<result>
againanything
dsgssgdfgdsfg <result1>A2<result1>
anythingiwith<>and"234and
newlinesandsoon

againanything
dsgssgdfgdsfg <result1>A3<result1>
anythingiwith<>and"234and
newlinesandsoon
<result>B3<result>
againanything
```

As Result i want 3 Results and 2 capturing groups (here: CG) and it should be

Result1:  1CG: A1  2CG: B1

Result2:  1CG: A2  2CG: null or just empty

Result3:  1CG: A3  2CG: B3

How to solve this and how to get null/empty when something doesnt exist?

Comment: Add your code here, not just in an external link.

Comment: i added the sample "code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
<result1>(.*?)<result1>(?:(?:.(?!<result1>))*?<result>(.*?)<result>)?
```

Can get your text in group #1 and group #2 (if exists). This regex will give:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `A1`
2.  `B1`

MATCH 2
1.  `A2`

MATCH 3
1.  `A3`
2.  `B3`
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iW8hP4/7)